# Autoconf, setcap and checkinstall

Tags: linux, autoconf, linux-capabilities, checkinstall

I have an autoconf project that contains a post-install hook like this:

```
install-exec-hook:
    setcap cap_net_raw+ep $(bindir)/myexecutable
```

I use checkinstall to package it up and install it on my local system, however after checkinstall is done, it appears that $(bindir)/myexecutable does not have any capabilities, as `getcap /usr/local/bin/myexecuatble` gives nothing, whereas I would expect `/usr/local/bin/myexecutable = cap_net_raw+ep`.

Comment: I bet if you ran with 'remake -x install` and paste the output, it would be clear what the problem is. If you don't have remake installed see https://bashdb.sf.net/remake

Comment: Did you make sure `setcap` ran successfully? In particular, did it have sufficient rights to access/manipulate files in `/usr/local/bin`?